# CodeIgniter menu/nav dilemma

Tags: php, codeigniter, navigation

I'm trying out CodeIgniter and the whole MVC pattern. I have installed [Colin Williams' Template library](http://www.williamsconcepts.com/ci/codeigniter/libraries/template/reference.html), but I get stuck when trying to think of the proper way to include two menus/navs: one general (maybe at the top) and one sidebar that is specific for each controller.

Either way, their placements are not relevant, I'm thinking about the general structure of the code. For now I have a function `get_menu()` in my model and the return from this is given as an argument when loading a partial template view for the sidebar. Or should I do it in the controller?

A buddy of mine gave me advice not to extend the default controller or model with i.e. a `MY_Controller`, but I don't know when when implementing the general menu? Or should I maybe hardcode this in the template config file?

I can find no guidelines for this type of task. Everywhere I go I find a new solution and many of them are not pretty and the other lot have a lot of duplicated code.

**Edit.** I've updated my code. I'm still undecided on how to write the top nav (probably in `MY_Controller` so that I can highlight the current page).

**MY_Controller.php**

```
abstract class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {
    protected $_nav;

    const CONTENT_REGION = 'content';
    const NAV_REGION = 'nav';
    const TITLE_REGION = 'title';

    const SIDEBAR_NAV_TEMPLATE = 'templates/sidebar_nav';

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->_load_nav();
    }

    abstract protected function _get_nav();

    protected function _load_nav() {
        $this->_nav = array('nav' => $this->_get_nav());
    }

    protected function _render() {
        $args = func_get_args();
        $n = func_num_args() - 1;

        if ($n < 2) {
            return;
        }

        $this->template->write(self::TITLE_REGION, $args[0]);

        for ($i = 1; $i < $n; $i++) {
            $this->template->write_view(self::CONTENT_REGION, $args[$i], $args[$n]);
        }

        $this->template->write_view(self::NAV_REGION, self::SIDEBAR_NAV_TEMPLATE, $this->_nav);
        $this->template->render();
    }

    protected function _set_active_view($active) {
        if ($active !== null && isset($this->_nav['nav'][$active])) {
            $this->_nav['nav'][$active]['class'] .= ' active';
        }
    }
}
```

**collection.php**

```
class Collection extends MY_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('collection_model');
    }

    protected function _get_nav() {
        return array(
            'collection/view' => array(
                'href'  => 'collection/view',
                'value' => 'View collection',
                'class' => 'icon-film'
            ),
            'collection/add' => array(
                'href'  => 'collection/add',
                'value' => 'Add title',
                'class' => 'icon-plus-sign'
            )
        );
    }

    public function index() {
        $this->view();
    }

    public function view() {
        $data['list'] = $this->collection_model->get_list();
        $this->_set_active_view('collection/view');
        $this->_render('View Collection', 'collection/view', $data);
    }
}
```

**sidebar_nav.php**

```
<ul class="nav nav-list bs-docs-sidenav">
    <?php

    foreach ($nav as $item) {
        echo '<li';

        if ($item['class'] !== null || $item['class'] !== '') {
            echo ' class="' . $item['class'] . '"';
        }

        echo '><a href="' . $item['href'] . '">' . $item['value'] . '</a></li>';
    }

    ?>
</ul>
```

How does this look? I might write a function `_render($title, $view, $data)` in `MY_Controller` that does all the template stuff. What do you think?

Another solution I've been thinking about is to remove `_get_nav()` and load the needed nav data from a config file, but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Unfortunately CI is not really implementing MVC pattern. View are not template, model is a layer and controller should not be sending data from model layer to templates. The best i can suggest is reading [this article](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html) and looking into ways of implementing real views.

Comment: Codeigniter is an MVC framework. We can design our own template and use it as a view. Thats how I have used it in my Codeigniter code generator at thephpcode.com. Defined a view as a template and passing content view name in to it and diplaying the content loaded from the content view name.

Answer (score 0):

What possible reason could your "buddy" have for telling you not to extend the controller class? This type of repetitive stuff is EXACTLY what that functionality is for... Create MY_Controller with the functions like getMenu and others you will use frequently throughout the site then just make collection extend MY_Controller rather than CI_Controller.

We not only extend the CI controller we then extend MY_Controller out to User_Controller and Admin_Controller to include specific functionality available only to those users.

I really can't for the life of me imagine why anyone would tell you not to do that.

Comment: Well, maybe he's not my "buddy" after all, haha. He was the one to recommend CI to me also, so I felt that maybe he had some knowledge on the subject. My OOP instinct told me to extend the classes though. A `get_menu()` in `MY_Controller` for the general (top) menu then and where to put the page specific (sidebar) menu functionality? In the controller as the model is supposed to handle only the database?

Comment: Maybe wise to create a `MY_Model` too? In case there are some database querys I want on all pages in the future?

Comment: Yep, nothing wrong with a MY_Model, we have multiple core classes and libraries extended in our application. Basically what you want to do is apply the DRY (don't repeat yourself) along with the MVC, so if logic dictates that it makes more sense to extend a library or core class then do it. That is why CI allows the extensions to begin with. We try to create a model per db table and controllers as necessary (not one per page, but some people do that).

Comment: Okay, but the menu functionality should remain in the controllers unless it is database related, yes? So a `get_top_menu()` and an abstract `get_sidebar_menu()` in `MY_Controller` to force extending classes to implement `get_sidebar_menu()`?

Comment: Yes. I assume by the way that the whole menu scheme thing like that is part of this template thing you're using. I build my own templates so static menus like that are just built in where they need to be in HTML.

Comment: Well, this "template thing" I'm using allows me to write to different predefined regions of my template. So by moving a few lines of HTML in the template I can have the sidebar to the left of the content. I think it's neat, but, of course, you would get the exact same thing with having a function `render()` in `MY_Controller`. I just didn't like the idea to have `templates/header.php` and `templates/footer.php` separate. The included menu view `menu/sidebar` is just a regular view looking outputting the contents of a variable `$menu` in a HTML list with Twitter styling.

Comment: Please take a look at my solution! :)

Comment: @Viktor Yes, you should only have database related code in your models. All else you can do in views (especially if static) or more usually in controllers.